# Instantiate Class Programmatically in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, class, design-patterns

I am working a big iOS project, the design is not a nice as I would like it to be, but I must stick to it. (life can be a bitch sometimes).

The thing is that we have a Library that basically let's you browse a catalog. You have a filter, where you specify a certain search criteria, and you are presented with a list were you can press on the items that you are interested. When you press an item, you can see a more detailed description of it.

The company were a work for, sells this same software to many different companies that have different catalogs. The idea is that the Library has all the main functionality, and the project that use it, might in some way extend or completely override some of the given interfaces.

To give you an example, imagine my library has 2 classes that manages 2 views. They would be "FilterViewController" and "DetailsViewControllers". In some place of the code this classes gets instantiated. It would look something like this

[image: Class diagram schema]

My approach is something like this:

**ProjectA side**

```
// Here I configure the library
Library.FilterViewClass = ProjectAFilterViewController;
Library.DetailsViewClass = ProjectADetailViewController;
```

**ProjectB side**

```
Library.FilterViewClass = ProjectBFilterViewController;
Library.DetailsViewClass = nil;
```

**Library side**

```
// Did the user configure the library?
if(self.FilterViewClass == nil){
    // I alloc the default ViewController
    myFilterViewController = [[FilterViewController alloc] init]; 
}else{
    // Here I would like to alloc the custom ViewController
    myFilterViewController = [[Library.FilterViewClass alloc] init]; // DaProblem!
}
```

The problem with that approach is that I actually don't know if it's possible to instantiate object programmatically. Or at least I don't know how. Maybe I am using the wrong approach, some direction would be appreciated. Txs in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get class from string you can use this function

```
Class cl = NSClassFromString(@"MyClass");
```

To get class of existing variable just call `class` method.

```
Class cl = [obj class]; // assuming obj1 is MyClass
```

Now you can create instance of `MyClass`

```
MyClass *myClass = (MyClass*)[[cl alloc] init];
...
[myClass release];
```

Comment: Txs mate, that is just what a was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
myFilterViewController = [[[Library.FilterViewClass class] alloc] init];
```

You can also instantiate from a class name, should that be useful to you:

```
id obj = [[NSClassFromString(@"MyClass") alloc] init];
```

Comment: Could `id` or `instanceof` solve all the dynamic class resolution problems like this one does? Any known issues?                                             Also, is this in anyway an example of bad design?

Answer (score 5):

```
Class someClass = [Foo1 class];
Foo * someObject = [[someClass alloc] init];
[someObject bar];

Class someClass2 = [Foo2 class];
Foo * someObject2 = [[someClass2 alloc] init];
[someObject2 bar];
```

Interface+Implementation:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject 
- (void)bar;
@end

@interface Foo1 : Foo

@end

@interface Foo2 : Foo
@end

@implementation Foo
- (void)bar {
    NSLog(@"abstract foo");
}
@end

@implementation Foo1
- (void)bar {
    NSLog(@"foo1bar");
}
@end

@implementation Foo2
- (void)bar {
    NSLog(@"foo2bar");
}
@end
```

Output:

```
2011-11-24 11:24:31.117 temp[21378:fb03] foo1bar
2011-11-24 11:24:31.118 temp[21378:fb03] foo2bar
```